# Open Datareader prevents POCO from getting filled

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to populate a POCO with the result of a query to my DB. The resultset has multiple rows so I'm just iterating over each result and populating the POCO with the data and I get this error :"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

Where am I messing up?

it goes like this:

**[Controller.cs]**

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Populates the inner Ads list
        /// </summary>
        public void FetchAds()
        {
            _ads = new List<Ad>();
            using (var context = (ApartmentDataEntities) DbContextFactory.GetInstance().GetDbContext<ApartmentDataEntities>())
            {
                foreach (var config in context.Configurations)
                {
                    _ads.Add(new AdModel(_basePath, config));
                }

            }

            AdsReady.SafeTrigger(this, new AdArray { Ads = _ads.ToArray() });
        }
```

**[AdModel.cs]** (inherits from the POCO)

```
    public AdModel(String baseFolder, Configuration apartment)
    {
        _baseFolder = baseFolder;
        GetAd(apartment);

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the Ad from the Database
    /// </summary>
    private void GetAd(Configuration apartment)
    {

        PropertyId = apartment.Property.id;
        PropertyName = apartment.Property.name;
        PropertyPhone = apartment.Property.phone;
        PropertyAddress = apartment.Property.address;
        AreaName = apartment.Property.MapArea.areaName;
        RegionName = apartment.Property.MapArea.Region.name;
        PropertyZipCode = apartment.Property.zipCode;
        ComissionRate = apartment.Property.comissionRate;
        Images = apartment.Property.Images.Select(img => img.id).ToArray();
        YearBuilt = apartment.Property.yearBuilt;
        Features = apartment.Property.features;
        Ammenities = apartment.Property.ammenities;
        CommunitySpecial = apartment.Property.communitySpecial;
        PetPolicy = apartment.Property.petPolicy;
        Size = apartment.size;
        Bathrooms = apartment.bathrooms;
        Bedrooms = apartment.bedrooms;
        Price = apartment.price;
        PropertyImages = apartment.Property.Images.Select(img => img.imageContents).ToArray();
        FloorplanImage = null;
        Floorplan = null;

        var configFloorplan = apartment.Images.SingleOrDefault();
        if (configFloorplan == null) return;

        FloorplanImage = configFloorplan.imageContents;
        Floorplan = configFloorplan.id;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is a better idea to do the projection to another model in the query itself. Like

```
_ads = (from apartment in context.Configurations
        let configFloorplan = apartment.Images.SingleOrDefault()
        select new AdModel
        {
            PropertyId = apartment.Property.id,
            PropertyName = apartment.Property.name,
            PropertyPhone = apartment.Property.phone,
            ...
            PropertyImages = apartment.Property.Images
                                      .Select(img => img.imageContents),
            FloorplanImage = configFloorplan.imageContents,
            Floorplan = configFloorplan.id
        }).ToList();
```

This ensures that everything is executed as one query. The problem with your approach is that while EF is reading `context.Configurations` other queries get executed to populate additional properties of the model.

This could be solved (maybe) by enabling multiple active result sets (MARS) in the connection string. But that does not fix the fact that you will be executing a potentially large number of queries (two queries for each materialized model).

Comment: I'm trying to do this and be as strict (for my own academic purposes) with MVC (Its a desktop app, but I want to force myself into doing things properly). Anyway, so I'm wondering how would this projection to another model in the query will affect the separation of concerns, since my controller is giving the model the data to work with (which now that I write sounds wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EntityFramework?  It's probably that the .Select's in your GetAdd are lazy loading and thus trying to query the DB while the outer query is still open.  Try adding toArray() after context.Configurations.  Seems I had to sprinkle these all over the place to avoid that error.